# How to stop windows from changing size (maximising) when dragging to screen edge in the GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, gnome-shell, debian-jessie, aero-snap

With Debian Jessie using the GNOME Shell Desktop, when I drag a window to the edge of the screen, it will attempt to maximise the window. This is similar to Windows' Aero Snap feature, which has [a well documented method of turning it on/off](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/disable-the-mouse-drag-window-arranging-feature-in-windows-7/).

How can I stop GNOME Desktop from doing this? I've looked through the options with `gnome-tweak-tool`, but haven't found anything relevant.

---

This is most likely a duplicate, but after searching for half an hour I give up. It is not related to GNOME Classic or [compiz](https://askubuntu.com/q/72452/45333), which have many answers.

---

**Update**: I've tried setting:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/overrides/edge-tiling false
```

(or finding it with the `dconf-editor` GUI) which is described:

> Summary: Enable edge tiling when dropping windows on screen edges
>   Description: This key overrides the key in org.gnome.mutter when running GNOME Shell.

After restarting, this does not fix the issue. I've also tried looking in with `gconf-editor` but haven't found anything related to "window", "shell" or "tiling".

So, still unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the "classic" gnome desktop and I found I need to do this:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/classic-overrides/edge-tiling false
```

Now the sadness is gone.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04:

```sh
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/edge-tiling false
```

I guess, Mutter was responsible.

Take a look at these two blog posts:

- [Disabling edge tiling on GNOME 3.26 / Ubuntu 17.10](http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2017/12/14/disabling-edge-tiling-on-gnome-3-26/)
- [Disabling edge tiling on GNOME 3.28 / Debian testing (buster)](http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2018/04/23/disabling-edge-tiling-on-gnome-3-28-debian-testing-buster/)

It looks like different solutions are needed for different GNOME3 versions or different systems.  (Some have already been suggested in the previous answers.)

Answer (score 2):

In the Debian 8 MATE desktop, you should be able to prevent windows from maximizing when they are moved to touch the top panel as follows.  (It may or may not work in GNOME.)  Open "System --> Control Center."  Click on "Windows."  (You can also get to "Windows" from "System --> Preferences.")  In the "Window Preferences" box that opens up, click on the tab "Placement."  Under "Window Snapping," uncheck the box "Enable side by side tiling."

Comment: This is the answer I needed.

All messing around with dconf, gconf, installing this and that is fine unless you aren't the admin on a machine.

In most cases, I'd suggest, knowing where to go in the labyrinthine settings noghtmare on MATE or other desktops is the way to go.

Hence: As Greg says - sorted.

The next problem: getting MATE to remember window placement. An elementary yet curiously absent feature, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

This may be relevant: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=72017#p507511

> The solution for gnome shell is:
>
> `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`
>
> then:
>
> `gconf-editor > / > desktop > gnome > shell > window > disable edge tiling option`
>
> ...then logout and log back in or restart... Automatic maximizing and
>   tiling of windows should be disabled.

Comment: I can only go as far as desktop > gnome, but cannot go past this. While it did not solve my issue, the +50 should go somewhere.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The documentation on Gnome Shell is nearly non-existent, it's a pity. Thanks for the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```